# Do all remote apps in angular micro front end need to be in the same angular workspace?

Tags: angular, webpack-5, micro-frontend

I know you can have multiple angular apps within a single angular workspace as remotes loaded into a shell angular app, but can you have multiple angular apps that are not in the same workspace? We have apps in different repositories, so they are not in the same workspace.

--- HOST APP webpack.config.js ---

```
const { shareAll, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  remotes: {
    "appOne": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js",    
    "appTwo": "http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js",    
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```

--- HOST APP main.ts ---

```
import { loadRemoteEntry } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

import('./bootstrap')
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

    Promise.all([
        loadRemoteEntry('http://localhost:4201', 'appOne'),
        loadRemoteEntry('http://localhost:4202', 'appTwo'),
    ])
        .catch((err) => console.error('Error loading remote entries', err))
        .then(() => import('./bootstrap'))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

--- HOST APP app-routing.module.ts (routes only) ---

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'app-one',
    loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
                            remoteName: 'appOne',
                            exposedModule: './appOne',
                        }).then((m) => m.AppOneModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'app-two',
    loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
                            remoteName: 'appTwo',
                            exposedModule: './appTwo',
                        }).then((m) => m.AppTwoModule)
  }
];
```

--- REMOTE APP ONE webpack.config.js ---

```
const { shareAll, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  name: 'appOne',

  exposes: {
    './appOne': './projects/app-one/src/app/app-one/app-one.module.ts',
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```

--- REMOTE APP ONE app-one.module.ts ---

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppOneComponent } from './app-one.component';
import { AppOneRoutingModule } from './app-one-routing-module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppOneComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule, AppOneRoutingModule]
})
export class AppOneModule {}
```

--- REMOTE APP ONE app-one-routing-module.ts ---

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppOneComponent } from './app-one.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: AppOneComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppOneRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: **Of course no**. The idea behind micro front end is to have a separate url for your remotes applications. Once you have deployed your remote app you just use the url in the shell app. All this is done in webpack configuration with module federation plugin

Comment: It seems like you are saying as long as you have a url to a deployed app, it can be added to a micro-front end via webpack configuration, meaning the multiple remote apps do not need to be in the same workspace. If this is the case then I was by your "no" :-)

Comment: Yes, I meant you don't need to have the remotes app in the same workspace. Please let me know if you need more info on the configuration

Comment: I'm new to using webpack for module federation, so any configuration hints you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Activate module federation in all the angular projects (shell and remotes)**

To do that you can use the schematic @angular-architects/module-federation with the command :

```
ng add @angular-architects/module-federation
```

This would generate the necessary configuration in the differents files :

```
- src/bootstrap.ts (bootstrap of AppModule)
- src/main.ts (import bootstrap)
- webpack.config.js (skeleton to use module federation)
- webpack.prod.config.js (skeleton to use module federation)
```

**Shell**

The shell app will use the router to lazy load the remotes modules(remote1, remote2)

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: HomeComponent,
   pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 {
   path: 'remote1',
   loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
                           remoteName: 'remote1App',
                           exposeModule: './Remote1',
                       }).then((m) => Remote1Module)
 },
];
```

So this **Remote1Module** module is not part of the shell project.

Your `main.ts file` will look like :

```
Promise.all([
    loadRemoteEntry('https://url_remote1', 'remote1App'),
    loadRemoteEntry('https://url_remote2', 'remote2App'),
])
    .catch((err) => console.error('Error loading remote entries', err))
    .then(() => import('./bootstrap'))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

So here you are trying to load the remote app with his **url** and **name**. The name must be the reference of the name you are going to use in routes(`remoteName: 'remote1App'`).

**Microfrontend project(Aka remote)**

So let say we are in the **remote1** project which have a module named **Remote1Module** This module contains the functionality we would like to expose in the Shell app.
In order to make this work we need to expose Remote1Module in the remote1 project webpack.

```
module.export = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'remote1',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
                './remote1App': './src/app/remote1.module.ts'
            }
        }),
        shared: share({
            ...
        })
    ]
}
```

This configuration exposes the **Remote1Module** under the public name **remote1App**. You can also share some packages with the Shell app by using the shared section.

**Trying out**

You can run first your remote app and then after your shell but this order is not necessary. I'm suggesting just to avoid the error

> Error loading remote entries ...

```
ng serve remote1App
ng serve shell
```

**All credits to Manfred Steyer** (https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/)

Comment: I've added code for what I have so far but I'm getting errors when I view the host app in Chrome:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

and

Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup module federation in all your angular project if you are not using mono repo approach

Comment: Yes, I've done that but no luck. Module federation in Angular seems fragile at best, and if the apps are not in the same workspace, even more so.

Comment: Can you please push your changes to github and give the url here. I have used Module Federation in a non mono repo approach. Everything works fine for me.

Comment: Is it dynamic or static? We have it working statically, but not dynamically, in which you specify remotes either in a manifest or config file.

Comment: @GregLafrance I have an approach to make remotes work dynamically. We can specific the remote url from shell application